# Я бы Вас не узнал, если бы не Ваша розовая шляпка

Tags: наклонение

*Я бы Вас не узнал, **если бы не Ваша розовая шляпка.***

Думаю, что поняла это предложение правильно: если бы на героине не было шляпы, ее не узнали бы. 
Получается, в предложении все равно присутствует сослагательное наклонение, даже если отсутствует глагольная форма на –л?

Спасибо!

Comment: Если честно, я не совсем согласна с корректурой вопроса, так как считаю, что сосл. накл. строится при помощи частицы БЫ и глагольной формы на-Л (которая просто омонимична прошедшему времени). Так как в русском сосл. накл. различие временной отнесенности возможно только в контексте, думаю, что такое различие (глагол на -Л versus прошед.время) целесообразно, чтобы отличaть соcл. накл. от формы собственно прошедшего времени.

Comment: Анонимочка, претензия принята - неточность устранена. "Сослагательное наклонение не имеет форм времени и форм лица, но имеет формы рода и числа..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Глагол не *отсутствует*, он просто *опущен*.

> ..., если бы не Ваша розовая шляпка.

эквивалентно

> ..., если бы не ***была на Вас*** Ваша розовая шляпка.

Вот Вам и глагол в прошедшем времени.